# How do I use an if statement to discretize a normal sample function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a normal random sample of 8 homework questions with a 50 point maximum each. However, I need to discretize the values such that if a random score is below 0, make it 0, and if it is above 50, make it 50. So far I have:

```
rawScores <- function(x) {
   rnorm(x, mean=40, sd=10)
   if (i < 0) i == 0
   if (i > 50) i == 50
}
rawScores(8)
```

However, the result rawScores(8) is "NULL". Can someone help me correctly format the if statement?

Comment: There are few problems in your code. Output from the `rnorm` isn't assigned anything. Maybe to `i`? If so, then `i` shouldn't be treated as a single element. The `==` is for logical comparisons.

Comment: What is `i` in your function ? and if `i = rnorm(...)` then your answer lies in accessing elements of numeric list

Answer (score 0):

Hope, that helps:

```
rawScores2 <- function(x) {
    ans <- rnorm(x, mean = 40, sd = 10)
    ans <- ifelse((ans < 0), 0, ans)
    ans <- ifelse((ans > 50), 50, ans)
    return(ans)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for